# Using `Test-NetConnection` with a proxy server

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am attempting to see if a port is open for network connectivity testing:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName watchdog.servicebus.windows.net -Port 9350
```

However this does not allow the use of a proxy, is there a way to use `Test-NetConnection` with a proxy server?

Comment: `Test-NetConnect` should use your proxy server if its correctly configured without having to specifically specify it. What error are you getting from the command?

Comment: If this is like other powershell cmdlets, you can configure the `System.Net.WebClient` (`WebRequest`?) class with a proxy and powershell will use it.  @JamesC. by default, you cannot set a proxy with `Test-NetConnection`; this is a lacking feature of the cmdlet that requires a workaround to support.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to configure the `System.Net.WebClient` class. Is this what you mean? `$FiddlerWP = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy "http://127.0.0.1:8888"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Proxy = $FiddlerWP

# This request will now get proxied through Fiddler
$WebClient.DownloadString("https://watchdog.servicebus.windows.net")
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName watchdog.servicebus.windows.net -Port 9350`

Answer (score 1):

Proxy servers usually work at layer 5. Test-netconnection, telnet, etc would not work with a proxy. However Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "watchdog.servicebus.windows.net"

Comment: Your answer could be improved by specifying how to use the `-Proxy` parameters and how to connect to the port specified in the question(9350).